# an error occured attempting to determine the process id of Webcore.exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm running an asp.net core 2 web app.  Been developing this app and env for almost 1 year. Windows did an update today and now I'm running into this error when trying  to debug. My application doesn't use SSL locally, so none of the google links apply to my case.

If I launch localhost:60856 in my browser directly after ctrl+f5, it gives me error "Bad gateway"
If I launch http://myapp.local:60856, it said can't be reached.

It's very important to me to be able to debug using the above url that i've setup locally because i have third party auth services that whitelist that url.

below is my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://myapp.local:60856",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "myappDotNet.WebCore": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://myapp.local:60856/"
    },
    "myappDotNet.WebCore.Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58576/"
    },
    "myappDotNet.WebCore.Live": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Live"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58577/"
    }
  }
}
```

my program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://myapp.local:60856")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.local

EDIT: if I change myapp.local to localhost in my launchSettings.json, it launches the site and works! But like i said i need the above hostname to be binded.
```

Comment: Did you change the hosts file using super user and were able to reload it to verify its contents. Alternatively , please ensure that your host file is not ignored : https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: @Riz My assumption is that this error wasn't actually caused by the windows update but rather by a code change or something else.  Have you tried to create a new Hello World app using the same myapp.local:60856 in your launchSettings.json (with this one shut down)?  This could help you determine if it happens to be an environment issue, issue with your code, or issue with third party code.

Comment: there's no code change as it works on my colleagues computers